# Linq Unit Test Suite

Tags: .net, linq, unit-testing

There are a set of 101 samples for LINQ [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)

I am sure I've seen someone make reference to a set of unit tests that test this functionality. It's primarily for someone creating a LINQ provider to make sure they implement everything correctly.

Can anyone provide a link to these unit tests if they exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackLINQ (http://www.raboof.com/Projects/BackLINQ/) is a project which implements a number of LINQ operations against .NET 2.0. The project is open source and they have posted the source code for their unit tests (http://backlinq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/test/BackLINQ.Tests/EnumerableFixture.cs). You may be able to adapt these tests for your needs.

There is also a CodePlex hosted project called 'A custom implementation of the .NET Standard Query Operators from LINQ' (http://linqsqo.codeplex.com/), which includes the source for a similar test suite.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I think this is the link I was looking for. Unless someone posts a more official list I will accept your answer.

Comment: No problem. Also just spotted this project: http://linqsqo.codeplex.com/, which again - includes the source code including tests for Enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for Jon Skeet's [EduLINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx).

Note that he's writinga LINQ to Objects implementation; some of his tests will not be applicable to DB-based implementations.